# How to Convert VC++ code to C#?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am having VC++ code, but i want to convert it to C#.I tried it using different software's,but it will not convert some of the functionality of VC++ to c#.How can i do it? or Is there any way to use VC++ code directly in c#?

for example this is VC++ method, i want to convert it to c#

```
    void init_gf (int poly)
  {

int m,b,p,v;

   // Return storage from previous setup



 if (log)

{

      free (log);

      free (alog);

      free (rspoly);

      rspoly = NULL;
   }

   // Find the top bit, and hence the symbol size

   for (b = 1, m = 0; b <= poly; b <<= 1)

      m++;

   b >>= 1;

   m--;

   gfpoly = poly;

   symsize = m;


   // Calculate the log/alog tables

   logmod = (1 << m) - 1;

   log = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * (logmod + 1));

   alog = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * logmod);


   for (p = 1, v = 0; v < logmod; v++)

   {

      alog[v] = p;

      log[p] = v;

      p <<= 1;

      if (p & b)

         p ^= poly;

   }

}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to do this. AFAIK You may need rewrite it.

Comment: Depending on what kind of code it is, you could try making a DLL out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just convert it automatically.

Converting the pure logic may be possible, but C++ and C# use completely different libraries. C++ uses the C runtime, MFC etc. and C# uses the .NET BCL. You'll need to learn at least a bit of the .NET equivalents of the classes and methods used by your C++ code.

For example, you could convert malloc calls by using arrays instead:
`(int*) malloc (sizeof (int) * logmod);` --> `new int[logmod]();`

If it's a lot of code, you could consider using C++/CLI and creating a mixed mode library, by leaving the C++ code as it is and exposing managed types that serve as a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to use VC++ code directly in c#?

C++/CLI applications are managed by .NET, and if that's the case then you can simply add a reference to the project or the dll in your C# project and use it normally

If it's native unmanaged code, you can make a wrapper for it using C# or C++/CLI, or you can call it direclty using P/Invoke.

**Edit:**
I was wrong about the caret operator, answered in a bit of a hurry, sorry about that! deleted.

Comment: the `^` operator in this case is used with the assignment operator (`^=`), which makes it a bitwise XOR operation.

Comment: That would be a Bitwise AND operation. You can check the full list of operators for C/C++ [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 0):

You have the below options

1. Have only the part of code which is not auto converted to be manually ported to C#
2. Make the VC++ code as COM Visible and use COM Inter-op from .NET
3. Complete re-write of the component in C# & using the VC++ code only to refer the application logic.

It might happen such that the converted code would contain unsafe operations and need to be compiled with unsafe flag. I would recommend you make a decision by looking at the auto converted code and the requirements in hand to see, whether it is worth converting using the auto converters.